# How to implement Content-Security-Policy in .NET 7?

Tags: html, asp.net-core, .net-7.0

**Explanation**

To increase the security of a .NET 7 application, I am trying to implement the "Content-Security-Policy". But for some reasons it does not work properly.

I get an almost blank page.

The web app contains of (the default `wwwroot` data):

- Bootstrap 5.3
- Javascript,
- Images
- Popups

I already tried :

[Asp net core Content Security Policy implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46846276/asp-net-core-content-security-policy-implementation)

and

https://content-security-policy.com/

**Question**

What is wrong with this code? How should it be, to work properly?

This is my `program.cs`:

```
var app = builder.Build();

 app.Use(async (context, next) =>
          {
              context.Response.Headers.Add("Content-Security-Policy", "default-src 'self' https://myexample.com; "script-src 'self' https://myexample.com;" +
"style-src 'self' https://myexample.com;" +
"img-src 'self' data: https://myexample.com; frame-ancestors 'none'");
             
              await next();
          });

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();
}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}
```

This is my `_Layout.cshtml` file:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - MyWebsite</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link href="~/lib/select2/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" asp-append-version="true" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/MyWebsite.styles.css" asp-append-version="true" />
</head>

<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/select2/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
```

The console

```
Content Security Policy: Couldn’t process unknown directive ‘+’ 2
[NoScript]:0 Prompt Hook installation https://mywebsite.com/MyStart log.js:32:13
Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at data: (“default-src”).
Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at inline (“style-src”). MyStart:15:1
Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at inline (“style-src”). MyStart:34:1
Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at inline (“style-src”). 10 MyStart
Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at inline (“style-src”). MyStart:74:1
Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at inline (“style-src”). 17 MyStart
Error in parsing value for ‘-webkit-text-size-adjust’.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.min.css:5:5749
Unknown pseudo-class or pseudo-element ‘-moz-focus-outer’.  Ruleset ignored due to bad selector. _form-range.scss:23:2
Ruleset ignored due to bad selector. _form-range.scss:38:4
Unknown pseudo-class or pseudo-element ‘-moz-placeholder-shown’.  Ruleset ignored due to bad selector. _floating-labels.scss:37:4
Unknown pseudo-class or pseudo-element ‘-moz-placeholder-shown’.  Ruleset ignored due to bad selector. _floating-labels.scss:58:4
Unknown pseudo-class or pseudo-element ‘-moz-placeholder-shown’.  Ruleset ignored due to bad selector. _floating-labels.scss:62:6
Unknown property ‘-moz-column-gap’.  Declaration dropped. _utilities.scss:74:12
Unknown property ‘-moz-column-gap’.  Declaration dropped. _utilities.scss:74:12
Unknown property ‘-moz-column-gap’.  Declaration dropped. _utilities.scss:74:12
Unknown property ‘-moz-column-gap’.  Declaration dropped. _utilities.scss:74:12
Unknown property ‘-moz-column-gap’.  Declaration dropped. _utilities.scss:74:12
Unknown property ‘-moz-column-gap’.  Declaration dropped. _utilities.scss:74:12
Unknown property ‘-moz-column-gap’.  Declaration dropped. _utilities.scss:74:12
Unknown property ‘-moz-column-gap’.  Declaration dropped. _utilities.scss:74:12
Unknown property ‘-moz-column-gap’.  Declaration dropped. _utilities.scss:74:12
Unknown property ‘-moz-column-gap’.  Declaration dropped. _utilities.scss:74:12
Unknown property ‘-moz-column-gap’.  Declaration dropped. _utilities.scss:74:12
Unknown property ‘-moz-column-gap’.  Declaration dropped. _utilities.scss:74:12
Unknown property ‘-moz-column-gap’.  Declaration dropped. _utilities.scss:74:12
Unknown property ‘-moz-column-gap’.  Declaration dropped. _utilities.scss:74:12
Unknown property ‘-moz-column-gap’.  Declaration dropped. _utilities.scss:74:12
Unknown property ‘-moz-column-gap’.  Declaration dropped. _utilities.scss:74:12
Unknown property ‘-moz-column-gap’.  Declaration dropped. _utilities.scss:74:12
Unknown property ‘-moz-column-gap’.  Declaration dropped. _utilities.scss:74:12
Unknown property ‘-moz-column-gap’.  Declaration dropped. _utilities.scss:74:12
Unknown property ‘-moz-column-gap’.  Declaration dropped. _utilities.scss:74:12
Unknown property ‘-moz-column-gap’.  Declaration dropped. _utilities.scss:74:12
Unknown property ‘-moz-column-gap’.  Declaration dropped. _utilities.scss:74:12
Unknown property ‘-moz-column-gap’.  Declaration dropped. _utilities.scss:74:12
Unknown property ‘-moz-column-gap’.  Declaration dropped. _utilities.scss:74:12
Unknown property ‘-moz-column-gap’.  Declaration dropped. _utilities.scss:74:12
Unknown property ‘-moz-column-gap’.  Declaration dropped. _utilities.scss:74:12
Unknown property ‘-moz-column-gap’.  Declaration dropped. _utilities.scss:74:12
Unknown property ‘-moz-column-gap’.  Declaration dropped. _utilities.scss:74:12
Unknown property ‘-moz-column-gap’.  Declaration dropped. _utilities.scss:74:12
Unknown property ‘-moz-column-gap’.  Declaration dropped. _utilities.scss:74:12
Unknown property ‘-moz-column-gap’.  Declaration dropped. _utilities.scss:74:12
Unknown property ‘-moz-column-gap’.  Declaration dropped. _utilities.scss:74:12
Unknown property ‘-moz-column-gap’.  Declaration dropped. _utilities.scss:74:12
Unknown property ‘-moz-column-gap’.  Declaration dropped. _utilities.scss:74:12
Unknown property ‘-moz-column-gap’.  Declaration dropped. _utilities.scss:74:12
Unknown property ‘-moz-column-gap’.  Declaration dropped. _utilities.scss:74:12
Expected ‘none’, URL, or filter function but found ‘alpha(’.  Error in parsing value for ‘filter’.  Declaration dropped. select2.min.css:1:2498
Expected ‘none’, URL, or filter function but found ‘progid’.  Error in parsing value for ‘filter’.  Declaration dropped. select2.min.css:1:9061
Expected ‘none’, URL, or filter function but found ‘progid’.  Error in parsing value for ‘filter’.  Declaration dropped. select2.min.css:1:10099
Expected ‘none’, URL, or filter function but found ‘progid’.  Error in parsing value for ‘filter’.  Declaration dropped. select2.min.css:1:11631
Expected ‘none’, URL, or filter function but found ‘progid’.  Error in parsing value for ‘filter’.  Declaration dropped. select2.min.css:1:12150
Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at inline (“default-src”). MyStart:164:1
Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at inline (“default-src”). MyStart:185:1
Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at inline (“default-src”). MyStart:203:1
Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at inline (“default-src”). MyStart:213:1
Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at inline (“default-src”). MyStart:221:1
Loading failed for the <script> with source “https://7896543.s3.amazonaws.com/001.js”. MyStart:1:1
Loading failed for the <script> with source “https://www.pagespeed-mod.com/v1/taas?id=cs&ak=b40b4e0329b50d95fe02b03a202d6279&si=84064dfa74404373adc7dd4d9344be15&tag=1005&rand=oude1692394540578bmbfvugeu&ord=5841258133796876”. MyStart:1:1
Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at https://7896543.s3.amazonaws.com/001.js (“default-src”). sandbox eval code:6:81829
Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at https://www.pagespeed-mod.com/v1/taas?id=cs&ak=b40b4e0329b50d95fe02b03a202d6279&si=84064dfa74404373adc7dd4d9344be15&tag=1005&rand=oude1692394540578bmbfvugeu&ord=5841258133796876 (“default-src”). sandbox eval code:6:94170
```

The generated Html page

```
 <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Mywebsite</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link href="/lib/select2/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/site.css?v=pAGv4ietcJNk_EwsQZ5BN9-K4MuNYS2a9wl4Jw-q9D0">
    <link href="/lib/select2/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Mywebsite.styles.css?v=Yc5nwZ2nMOGXYVoXuba_CcptBKgP6RpaMUJRrcu05Sg">


    <style>

        .vertical-center {
            margin: 0;
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
            transform: translateY(-50%);
        }

    </style>

<script type="text/javascript" async="" src="https://ssl.google-analytics.com/ga.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="//7896543.s3.amazonaws.com/001.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" async="" src="//www.pagespeed-mod.com/v1/taas?id=cs&amp;ak=b40b4e0329b50d95fe02b03a202d6279&amp;si=84064dfa74404373adc7dd4d9344be15&amp;tag=1005&amp;rand=oude1692394540578bmbfvugeu&amp;ord=4310742209651695.5"></script></head>



<body style="background-color: #8de6fd; text-align: center;max-width: 96%;">
    <header>

                                  <style>
         .body-container {
            /*remove the container default padding attribute*/
            padding-left: 0px;
            padding-right: 0px;
            /*increase width as per your need*/
            min-width: 100%;
        max-width: 100%;
           /* max-width:1350px;*/
        }

        .content {
          margin-left: 0px;
        }
        
      </style>

<br>

<div class="row" style="width:100%;">
    <div class="col-md-12">

    </div>
</div>

    </header>

    <div b-87ljh5gmcq="" class="container body-container">

        <br b-87ljh5gmcq="" class="collapse d-sm-table-cell">
        <main b-87ljh5gmcq="" role="main" class="pb-3 content" style="max-width:1250px;">
            
    
<style>
    .vertical-center {
        margin: 0;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
        transform: translateY(-50%);
    }

    .pulse{
        width: 70px;height: 70px;
background-color: none;
border-radius: 50%;
position: relative;
animation: animate 3s linear infinite
    }

.pulse i{
    position: relative;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
font-size: 30px;color: #fff;
height: 100%;cursor: pointer
}

@keyframes animate{
    0%{box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgb(0, 162, 232, 0.7) , 0 0 0 0 rgb(0, 162, 232, 0.7)}
    40%{box-shadow: 0 0 0 20px rgb(0, 162, 232, 0) , 0 0 0 0 rgb(0, 162, 232, 0.7)}
    80%{box-shadow: 0 0 0 20px rgb(0, 162, 232, 0) , 0 0 0 20px rgb(0, 162, 232, 0)}
    100%{box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgb(0, 162, 232, 0) , 0 0 0 20px rgb(0, 162, 232, 0)}
    }

</style>





    <div class="vertical-center" style="min-width: 96%; max-width: 96%;">
        <div style="text-align:center;">

                <a class="btn btn-sm " style="text-align: center;" href="/MyStart">
Login
                </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" style="width:100%;">
        <div class="col-md-12">

        </div>
    </div>






        </main>
    </div>


    <script src="/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

    <script src="/js/site.js?v=4q1jwFhaPaZgr8WAUSrux6hAuh0XDg9kPS3xIVq36I0"></script>



    
<script src="/lib/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>


<iframe src="about:blank" style="display: none;"></iframe></body>
```

Comment: What messages do you get in the browser console?

Comment: Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at data: (“default-src”).  Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at inline (“style-src”).  Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at inline (“script-src”).  Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at https://7896543.s3.amazonaws.com/001.js (“script-src”).

Comment: Please add the console message directly to your question. And also add the HTML code that refers to the style sheets and javascript files. Obviously, your content security policy is working but your HTML is not ready for it.

Comment: Without seeing the generated HTML, it's difficult to diagnose all the problems. And there are several ones. The first one is that you are using inline styles, probably like `<p style="...">`. To fix it, move them to a stylesheet or use nonces, `unsafe-inline` etc. There are further issue on line 164, 185 etc. I can't diagnose it without seeing those lines. Then further scripts are loaded from `7896543.s3.amazonaws.com` and `www.pagespeed-mod.com`. If that's ok, they must be included in the policy or hosted on the same server.

Comment: Inserted the html page too. For some strange reason i get Google analytics .js and amazonaws .js which i do not use.

Comment: The added HTML has about 140 lines. So I can't tell you what the problem at line 164, 185 etc. is. These lines might been added by Javascript code. Your policy is good for loading files from your host. But it does not work for inline styles and third-party scripts. You will have to look at them one by one and decide what to do with it. If you have a problem with a particular one, ask another more specific question.